# Why, with Protractor/WebDriverIO/..., does an element has to be visible to click on it?

Tags: protractor, click, element, visible

I'm migrating tests written in Protractor to WebDriverIO and I noticed some tests fail because an element is not "visible" when "I" (the test) want to click on it.

Why is that? Aren't we supposed to work with the DOM? What does it mean to be visible in headless tests? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

To make my test work, I have to scroll (which even is hard to make work!) the element I want to click on into view (e.g. `await element.scrollIntoView({ block: 'center' });`).